# initialization a javascript array using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to initialize a array in JS using a variable.

```
var list= "0,1";
var a = new Array(list);
```

As a output I want a[0] to be 0 and a[1] to be 1

Any other way is to parse list and put all the value to a one by one.

Any way to do it in one line

I want integer Array

Comment: that's some crazy code you got there.  Why would a string separated by commas ever convert to an array?  See @Pointy answer below.  Makes much more sense.

Comment: You want them to be strings or numbers? Please clarify. And what is the source of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` and `map`:

```
var a = list.split(',').map(parseFloat);
```

This sets `a` to `[0, 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers

```
var list= "[0,1]";
arrayList = eval(list);
```

This is also one way to do

Comment: It's generally considered a good practice to avoid using `eval()` unless it's really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var a = [0, 1];
```

That's if you want the elements to be numbers. If you want them to be strings:

```
var a = ["0", "1"];
```